# How can you get woocomemrce to give you multiple licensing options for a downloadable product?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, licensing

I have music I want to sell online and make downloadable. But, this music needs to be available under difference licensing options to the buyer, and the buyer needs to be able to browse many different songs of a single category and pick out different songs to add to their cart without leaving the page. How can I do this with product options in woocommerce? Maybe custom attributes has something to do with it, but it's not very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variations to set the different prices for the various licences, but that's a lot of duplication as you'd need to enter the prices and attach the same download file to each variation manually. A better option would be to use the [Product Addons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/) plugin, which will allow you to attach any number of standard licence price upgrades (eg, Licence A +£0, Licence B +£50, Licence C +£100, etc)

Comment: That's too expensive just for a basic licensing option that I can take care of manually, and that's just despite the fact that I can buy an entire store or player plugin that has licensing options in addition to various either features for less than the single site price of that plugin.